# How to convert svg tag to ".svg" file

Tags: html, css, svg

I need convert an svg html element to a ".svg" file

I have tried creating a text file pasting the svg code into the text file then changing the extension on the text file to ".svg".

Opening the svg file in the browser shows the error below.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<svg class="shape-section__shape" width="1440" height="124" viewBox="0 0 1440 84" fill="#c4e0fd" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="M0 83C454.33-24.774 928.696-27.898 1384.99 71.96L1440 83v2H0Z" fill="#c4e0fd"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @MattHamer5 — That's not a tag, it's a declaration, and won't make a difference here.

Answer (score 1):

See [MDN's Getting Started Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Getting_Started):

> ```
> <svg version="1.1"
>      width="300" height="200"
>      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
> ```

Browsers will automatically apply SVG styling to SVG elements based on their namespace.

The message you got indicates that you failed to specify the namespace using the `xmlns` attribute.

Add it.